# How to validate that user enter only current or previous MM/YYYY and not future MM/YYYY

Tags: asp.net, validation, datetime

I am trying to do validation on textbox "TextBoxToMonth" such that user enter only current or previous MM/YYYY and not enter future MM/YYYY.

So user can enter dates like 09/2015  and not able to submit future dates like 09/2030. I am using below comparevalidator. But I am not sure what to enter in ValueToCompare property.How do I achieve this validation?

```
     <asp:CompareValidator ControlToValidate="TextBoxToMonth" 
                Type="Date" runat="server" ID="cvToMonth" Display="None"  ValidationGroup="RepGroup" 
 ErrorMessage="<b>Invalid Date Range</b><br />You must enter a End Month that is less than or equal to Current Month." 
        Operator="LessThanEqual"  ValueToCompare="<%# DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>">
    </asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in a `CompareValidator`.  You'll need to use a `CustomValidator` instead.

```html
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="YourTextBox"
                     ErrorMessage="YourErrorMessage" OnServerValidate="OnServerValidate" />
```

```csharp
protected void OnServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    DateTime dt;
    args.IsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(args.Value, "MM/yyyy",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt) 
        && dt <= DateTime.Today;
}
```

One minor but important detail - since "today" isn't the same all over the world at the same time, it's possible that `DateTime.Today` when run on your server could be a different date than the one the end-user is observing.  If you are at the end of the month, and they're on the first of the next month, then this test will fail.

To validate *perfectly*, you would need to know the time zone of the end-user.  Alternatively, you could add an extra day to err on the other side.